# Large background images and fps reducing

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I've made a game with parallax backround images in it. 
Background consists from four different moving layers. Without bg I have 60fps on iPhone4. But when I add it on the stage fps is reduced to 45-50. 
I divided bg images into tiles 128x128. Problem still exists. All images in png extension with alpha channel. I'm using the last version of cocos2-x. Have anybody an idea why fps reduced so much?

Comment: Are you drawing them in one draw call using `CCSpriteBatchNode`?

Comment: Yes. But I didn't notice any difference in perfomance in my current situation.

Comment: one batch node for all of them? Common mistake is to use one batch node per sprite

Comment: I'm using one batch for one background layer. Because different layers saved in different atlases.